# draw a block diagram for the system

Tags: control-system, block-diagram

A system is represented by the following equation:
$$\frac{^2}{^2} + 8\frac{}{} + 9 = 1$$

By taking the initial conditions, (0) = 1, ̇(0) = −1, draw a block diagram for the 
system. The transfer function will be as following:

$$\frac{^2}{^2} + 8\frac{}{} + 9 = ()$$

Comment: IME, we usually define systems in EE in terms of an input signal and an output signal. What is the input signal in your first equation?

Comment: Hello Kasut, welcome to EESE. Is this question from a homework? Please add all the work you have done so far and also the homework tag, so that it identify the question as such.

Comment: A transfer function does not exist if there are non-zero initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

One way to represent that equation by a block diagram would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2xJmT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>